# How to get the value of attribute using the on click function of Jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a question regarding my code; Why when I click the second table row, the first value of attribute is alerting.

For example,
in the first table row I have an attribute value of "30" and the second attribute value is 31, so when I click the second table row, the first table row value is showing, not the value of the second row.

Here is my code.
First, I need to append the response to the table, so I have here:

```
 $('#edit_chainingBuild').append("<tr class='clickable-row'><td>" + Qty + "</td><td>" + Condiments + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td><td style='display:none;' data-attribute-chain-id="+menu_builder_details_id +" class='data-attribute-chain-id'>"+menu_builder_details_id+"</td></tr>");
```

So, now I want to get the value of each attribute of "data-attribute-chain-id"

I have here the code:

```
    $('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row',function(e){


      $('table#edit_chainingBuild tr').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');

      var find_each_id_will_update = $('.data-attribute-chain-id').attr('data-attribute-chain-id');
      alert(find_each_id_will_update);

      $('#EditcondimentsBuilderModal').modal('show');


});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In your following code:

```
var find_each_id_will_update = $('.data-attribute-chain-id').attr('data-attribute-chain-id');
```

You are finding an element by class 'data-attribute-chain-id', which is returning first element in the dom. Instead you need to get element with same class 'data-attribute-chain-id' inside the clicked row.

```
var find_each_id_will_update = $(this).find('.data-attribute-chain-id').attr('data-attribute-chain-id');
```

or

```
var find_each_id_will_update = $(this).children('.data-attribute-chain-id').attr('data-attribute-chain-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vishal Bhavsar's answer is nice.

If your situation allowed, why not move `data-attribute-chain-id` to `<tr>`

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild').append("<tr data-attribute-chain-id=" + menu_builder_details_id + " class='clickable-row'><td>...</td></tr>");
```

And then

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row',function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('data-attribute-chain-id'));
});
```